# PHP calling a function and printing the value the function returns

Tags: php, function

I've tried a number of different approaches and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong (but, undoubtedly, it's an amateur mistake).  So, here it goes: I have a function defined in one file as follows:

```
    <?php
    function getServer() {
        $server = $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME];

        if ($server == 'ntowl.com')
        {
            $server = 'Practice Area';
        } else {
            $server = 'localhost';
        }

        return $server;
    }
    ?>
```

As you can see, the return value is $server.  Now, I'm trying to print that value on another page by calling the getServer function.  Here's one of the ways I've attempted:

```
    <?php
        include "assignment_4_common_functions.php";    

        getServer($server);

        print "Server: $server";
    ?>
```

Any suggestions on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return values are assigned.

```
$server = getServer();
```

Your code is passing the value to the function. So it's never changed.

Comment: Thank you!  That helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it gave me the result I wanted:

```
    <?php
        include "assignment_4_common_functions.php";    

        print "Server: " .getServer(). "";
    ?>
```